# Theoretical basis behind calculation of steady state probability distribution of 2-state Markov chain from its transition matrix

Tags: probability, matrices

I am studying stochastic processes and have stumbled on a result that is puzzling me. I have searched elsewhere for an answer without luck so hoping some proper mathematicians here can explain the result for me.

Given a two-state Markov process with probability transition matrix
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
&\begin{matrix}0&1\end{matrix}\\
\hline
\begin{matrix}0\\ 1\end{matrix}
&\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}
\end{array}
$$

I have found that the simplest way to calculate its steady-state probability distribution is :

state 0: $c \over {b + c}$

state 1: $b \over {b + c}$

This result holds for all examples I have tried, but I have been unable to explain it from theory, so cannot prove it. My questions are:

1. what is the theoretical explanation for this result?
2. does it extend to any $n\times n$ transition matrix?

Comment: I have just found that 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259852/how-to-compute-the-stationary-distribution-of-a-2-times-2-transition-probabili?rq=1

answers my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specific to two-state chains. Note that $a=1-b$ and $d=1-c$ for the matrix to be a probability transition matrix hence $(b,c)$ determines entirely the probability transition matrix and the distribution $(\pi_0,\pi_1)$ is stationary if and only if
$$
\pi_0=a\pi_0+c\pi_1,\qquad\pi_1=b\pi_0+d\pi_1.
$$
This system is equivalent to the single equation
$$
b\pi_0=c\pi_1.
$$
The normalization $\pi_0+\pi_1=1$ yields the values in the question.

Comment: Clear, concise and helpful answer, many thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.